# NOT operation missing

Tags: mips

I was trying to figure out about the "not" instruction for MIPS and i couldn't figure out yet ...
I saw a lot of examples on the net and tried them.
For example :

```
not $t0, $t1
```

and

```
nor $t0, $t1, $zero
```

But when i try with the simulator MARS both of those instructions, the answer i get, is: -1 or -2.
When it should be 1 or 0 for me.

What i want is:

!1  (= 0) or  !0 (=1)

What's the problem ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: Here is a resource that should answer your question. http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/bitwise.html

Comment: hummm...i'm confused... Where should i see the answer ? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i want is:
>
> !1 (= 0) or !0 (=1)

In that case you should do something like this:

```
sltu $t0, $zero, $t1
xori $t0, $t0, 1
```

The `sltu` instruction checks if zero is less than `$t1`, and sets `$t0` to 1 or 0 depending on the result of that comparison. Since it's an unsigned comparison, it essentially becomes the same as `$t0 = ($t1 != 0) ? 1 : 0`. And because what you want is `$t0 = ($t1 == 0) ? 1 : 0` we use an eXclusive OR afterwards to invert the 0 to a 1 or vice versa.

---

The `not` instruction performs [a bitwise NOT operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). That is, it inverts *all* bits (all 0s to 1s, and all 1s to 0s). So if the input is 0 you get 0xFFFFFFFF as the result (which can also be interpreted as -1). And if the input is 1 you get 0xFFFFFFFE (which can also be interpreted as -2).